# List and Count items with a JOIN with SQL

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to create a basic rapport from these 2 tables:

**Table Products**

```
|--------|----------------|----------|
| PRO_Id | PRO_CategoryId | PRO_Name |
|--------|----------------|----------|
|      1 |             98 | Banana   |
|      2 |             98 | Apple    |
|--------|----------------|----------|
```

**Table Categories**

```
|--------|----------|
| CAT_Id | CAT_Name |
|--------|----------|
|     98 | Fruits   |
|     99 | Other    |
|--------|----------|
```

What I needed is this output:

```
|------------|
| Categories |
|------------|
| Fruits (2) |
|------------|
```

I would like a report listing all the categories from `Categories` but only when product from `Products` has a link (with is the case form Fruits but not for Other).

This is where I am actually:

```
SELECT CAT_Name, COUNT(PRO_Name IN sum)
FROM Categories
JOIN Products
ON Products.PRO_CategoryId = Categories.CAT_Id as sum
ORDER BY CAT_Name ASC
```

Anyone to help me with this please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close.  You need to get rid of the garbage in the query and use a `group by`:

```
SELECT c.cat_name, COUNT(*)
FROM Categories c JOIN
     Products p
     ON p.PRO_CategoryId = c.CAT_Id
GROUP BY c.CAT_Name ;
```

Notes:

- `SELECT *` is not appropriate for an aggregation query.  What you want to select is.
- This puts the count in a separate column which seems to be your intention, despite the sample results.
- `COUNT(pro_name in sum)` doesn't make sense.
- `as sum` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot and for your explanations.